# How do I use my PC as a virtual computer on Android/Mac

Tags: virtual-machine, remote-desktop, vmware

In my organization, we work through VMware on Cloud Desktops or VDI machines. I'm aware that a virtual machine can be installed on PC but Is there any way to use my PC on different machine Android/mac through VMware or any other software like I do in the office.

Just need a push in the right direction.

Comment: Your question does not make a lot of sense to me, sorry. What do you mean by "using your PC as a virtual computer on Android"? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: It's pretty obvious that he's trying to use his PC remotely from and Android or Mac, like they're doing with VDI at their office...

Answer (score -1):

You can connect to a Windows (not Starter or Home edition) using a [Remote Desktop client](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/remote/remote-desktop-services/clients/remote-desktop-clients). It's not a virtual machine, as you are just running a remote machine remotely, but this is probably what you are looking for -- VDI runs the PC on a virtual machine on a server, but you connect to it through Remote Desktop or similar.